# OpenShift v2 EOL Date Extended for Paying Users

Tags: openshift

The EOL date has been adjusted for "Paying Users" to 31st December 2017.

I use the Bronze service which is free but I pay for 9gb of storage every month. So I am uncertain if I am considered to be a "Paying User".

Anyone have an answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a paying customer, you should have received an email about the extended end of life. If you didn't, [contact us here](https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html) and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I see [an update on the blog](https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/) about the EOL.